# Should I use "is something" or "are something" for plural nouns?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Should I use **is** or **are** in this sentence?

> Vocabulary-based games **is** something that he enjoys the most.

Comment: What verb would you normally use with a plural noun? Why do you think this one is different?

Comment: @Catija - "**What verb would you normally use with a plural noun?**" - Sometimes "are", sometimes "is" ("His statistics is wrong", "That crossroads is far away from here", etc). "**Why do you think this one is different?**" Different from what?

Comment: You don't use "is" with plural nouns.

Comment: @Catija - Check my examples in the comment above.

Comment: "A crossroads" is not plural. It is a singular thing that just happens to have a plural word on the end. The same with statistics... statistics meaning the form of math... If you're talking about several different stats (plural), then it should be "His statistics **are** wrong". Nothing about "games" is possibly singular. You are talking about several different games, so it's plural.

Comment: @Catija - Webster says, "Usually plural but singular or plural in construction" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crossroads), which leaves me suspended in the air - just like in many other such cases, hence, my question.

Comment: Stop looking at the odd exceptions and look at the actual example here. Does the definition for "games" ever allow for it to be singular? Even if you're looking at your crossroads example, the word "that" implies that it must be singular, so the "is" is obvious.

Comment: Here's a better dictionary. As you can see, "Crossroads" is the singular and plural forms: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/crossroads

Comment: @Catija - I've seem many native speakers say "His statistics IS wrong", and when I asked them why not "are", they would tell me that in this particular case they simply meant ''the whole body of statistics without going into detail", therefore, they used "is". Well, following that logic, I can also say that I mean the whole collection of games without going into detail.

Comment: @Catija - "**Here's a better dictionary**" - How do you know that Longman is better than Webster?

Comment: Statistics is a field of study; a branch of mathematics (also singular). It's a subject. Games are not a monolith the way statistics or mathematics are.

Comment: @Catija - In my case games is one of the aspects of teaching process.

Comment: @Catija - BTW, in the sentence "His statistics is wrong" it is not really a field of study what is meant, but rather someone's calculations, isn'it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vocabulary-based games **are** things that he enjoys the most.

*Vocabulary-based games* is clearly plural. Please use the plural copular(are). For words like "crossroads", that's just how the word is, it's plural in form but it can be singular or plural in use. Thus, the singular and plural form for *crossroads* is *crossroads*.

Comment: "**Vocabulary-based games is clearly plural**" - Why did you use **is** in this sentence?

Comment: @brilliant Singular or plural the word depends on what you want it to mean. In this context, I take "vocabulary-based games" as a phrase not literally the game.

Comment: So, would it be correct to say "is" then in this case: "There are many different methods that you can use to direct his energy into the course of studying. We usually use five methods: songs, skits, quizzes, vocabulary-based games, and discussions. Vocabulary-based games is something that he enjoys the most"?

Comment: @brilliant Yes, if you consider "vocabulary-based games" as **one** of the methods.